# Replace newlines with a space in all files in a directory - Python

Tags: python, text, file-io

I have about 4000 txt files in a directory. I'd like to replace newlines with spaces in each file using a for loop. Actually, the script works for that purpose but when I save the file, it doesn't get saved or it gets saved with newlines again. Here is my script;

```
import glob
path = "path_to_files/*.txt"
for file in glob.glob(path):
    with open(file, "r+") as f:
        data = f.read().replace('\n', ' ')
        f.write(data)
```

As I said I'm able to replace the newlines with a space, but at the end, it doesn't get saved. I also don't get any errors.

Comment: It's almost always a bad idea to open a file in the 'r+' mode (because of the way the current position is handled). Open a file for reading, read the data, replace the newlines, open the same file file for writing, write the data.

Comment: Without `f.seek()`, I don't see this working as you state it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To further elaborate my comment ("*It's almost always a bad idea to open a file in the 'r+' mode (because of the way the current position is handled). Open a file for reading, read the data, replace the newlines, open the same file file for writing, write the data*"):

```
for file in glob.glob(path):
    with open(file) as f:
        data = f.read().replace('\n', ' ')
    with open(file, "w") as f:
        f.write(data)
```

Comment: That did the trick, also thanks for pointing out the 'r+' mode. However, when I open the file separately to save the file, the loop takes longer to complete. Do you think that trade-off worths?

Comment: If it is a one-time deal, I would prefer a loop that has a clear structure. You decide.

Comment: I got you. It seems more elegant too. I used it that way in my script.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset file position to 0 with `seek` and then truncate the leftover with `truncate` after you finishing writing the replacement string.

```
import glob
path = "path_to_files/*.txt"
for file in glob.glob(path):
    with open(file, "r+") as f:
        data = f.read().replace('\n', ' ')
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(data)
        f.truncate()
```

Comment: what does `truncate` do?

Comment: It truncates a file at the current position, unless a position is specified. See: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/file_truncate.htm

Comment: Why do you need the `truncate` if both the old and the new files have exactly the same size?

Comment: This also works with the answer above, but do you think resetting a position is a safer way?

Comment: @DyZ You're absolutely right that `truncate` isn't needed in this very case, but in general you want to truncate if you aren't sure about the size of the replacement versus the original in advance. I just put it there so that the solution is more generic.

Comment: @mburakergenc There's no harm in resetting file position. The only concern is if your replacement string is shorter than the original string then you will end up with leftover of the original, which is why I had this `truncate` method in the end, which, as DyZ pointed out, isn't actually needed because in your case your replacement string will always be of the same size as the original.